# scraping a table and getting more info from a link

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I am using python and beautifulsoup to scrape a table...I have a pretty good handle on getting most of the information I need. shortened table of what I am trying to scrape.

```
<tr> <td><a href="/wiki/Joseph_Carter_Abbott" title="Joseph Carter Abbott">Joseph Carter  Abbott</a></td> <td>1868–1872</td> <td>North Carolina</td> <td><a href="/wiki/Republican_Party_(United_States)" title="Republican Party (United States)">Republican</a></td>
</tr> 
<tr> <td><a href="/wiki/James_Abdnor" title="James Abdnor">James Abdnor</a></td> <td>1981–1987</td> <td>South Dakota</td> <td><a href="/wiki/Republican_Party_(United_States)" title="Republican Party (United States)">Republican</a></td> </tr> <tr> <td><a href="/wiki/Hazel_Abel" title="Hazel Abel">Hazel Abel</a></td> <td>1954</td> <td>Nebraska</td> <td><a href="/wiki/Republican_Party_(United_States)" title="Republican Party (United States)">Republican</a></td> 
</tr>
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_former_United_States_senators

I want Name, Description, Years, State, Party.

The Description is the first paragraph of text on each persons page. I know how to get this independently, but I have no idea on how to integrate it with Name, Years, State, Party because I have to navigate to a different page.

oh and I need to write it to a csv.

Thanks!

Comment: You'll have to write some code to read both of the web pages and marry up the information contained in them.  Oh, and to write it to a CSV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to expound on @anrosent's answer: sending a request mid-parsing is one of the best and most consistent ways of doing this. However, your function that gets the description has to behave properly as well, because if it returns a `NoneType` error, the whole process is turned into disarray.

The way I did this on my end is this (note that I'm using the Requests library and not urllib or urllib2 as I'm more comfortable with that -- feel free to change it to your liking, the logic is the same anyway):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import requests as rq
import csv

ofile = open("presidents.csv", "wb")
f = csv.writer(ofile)
f.writerow(["Name","Description","Years","State","Party"])
base_url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_former_United_States_senators"
r = rq.get(base_url)
soup = bsoup(r.content)
all_tables = soup.find_all("table", class_="wikitable")

def get_description(url):
    r = rq.get(url)
    soup = bsoup(r.content)
    desc = soup.find_all("p")[0].get_text().strip().encode("utf-8")
    return desc

complete_list = []
for table in all_tables:
    trs = table.find_all("tr")[1:] # Ignore the header row.
    for tr in trs:
        tds = tr.find_all("td")
        first = tds[0].find("a") 
        name = first.get_text().encode("utf-8")
        desc = get_description("http://en.wikipedia.org%s" % first["href"])
        years = tds[1].get_text().encode("utf-8")
        state = tds[2].get_text().encode("utf-8")
        party = tds[3].get_text().encode("utf-8")
        f.writerow([name, desc, years, state, party])

ofile.close()
```

However, this attempt ends at the line just after `David Barton`. If you check the page, maybe it has something to do with him occupying two lines to himself. This is up to you to fix. Traceback is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nanashi/Documents/Python 2.7/Scrapers/presidents.py", line 25, in <module>
    name = first.get_text().encode("utf-8")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

Also, notice how my `get_description` function is before the main process. This is obviously because you have to define the function first. Finally, my `get_description` function is not nearly perfect enough, as it can fail if by some chance the first `p` tag in the individual pages is not the one you want.

Sample of result:

[image]

Pay attention to the erroneous lines, like Maryon Allen's description. This is for you to fix as well.

Hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Whoop! Thanks! Sorry I didnt see this earlier! I am amazed by the skill level of members of this site. What I work at for days take you a matter of minutes.

Comment: @user3485563 and also, look through your other previous questions and accept if any of them deserve, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for accepting. @alecxe: Thanks. This is not the best possible answer though, but not a bad scrape. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using BeautifulSoup, you won't be navigating to the other page in the stateful, browser-like sense so much as just making another request for the other page with the url like *wiki/name*. So your code might look like

```
import urllib, csv

with open('out.csv','w') as f:

    csv_file = csv.writer(f)

    #loop through the rows of the table
    for row in senator_rows:
        name = get_name(row)

        ... #extract the other data from the <tr> elt

        senator_page_url = get_url(row)

        #get description from HTML text of senator's page
        description = get_description(get_html(senator_page_url))

        #write this row to the CSV file
        csv_file.writerow([name, ..., description])

#quick way to get the HTML text as string for given url
def get_html(url):
    return urllib.urlopen(url).read()
```

Note that in python 3.x you'll be importing and using `urllib.request` instead of `urllib`, and you'll have to decode the `bytes` the `read()` call will return.
It sounds like you know how to fill in the other `get_*` functions I left in there, so I hope this helps!